# Max de um campo numérico retornando NA

Tags: r

Estou iniciando no aprendizado de R e me deparei com uma situação que não estou entendendo. Baixei os dados do ENEM 2014 (arquivo CSV) e fiz a leitura usando:

```
dados_enem <- read.csv(file="MICRODADOS_ENEM_2014.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Quando peço para calcular a máxima, mínima ou média de um determinado campo numérico, ele retorna perfeitamente. Por exemplo, o campo NU_NOTA_REDACAO:

```
max(dados_enem$NU_NOTA_REDACAO)  
min(dados_enem$NU_NOTA_REDACAO)  
mean(dados_enem$NU_NOTA_REDACAO)

    > max(dados_enem$NU_NOTA_REDACAO)  
    [1] 1000  
    > min(dados_enem$NU_NOTA_REDACAO)  
    [1] 0  
    > mean(dados_enem$NU_NOTA_REDACAO)  
    [1] 323.4219
```

Porém, ao fazer o mesmo para os campos NOTA_CN ou NOTA_CH, ambos do mesmo formato que o NU_NOTA_REDACAO, me é exibido NA:

```
max(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)  
min(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)  
mean(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)
```

> max(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)
>   [1] NA
>   min(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)
>   [1] NA
>   mean(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)
>   [1] NA

Já tentei forçar a conversão para numérico, mas o resultado foi o mesmo:

> dados_enem$NOTA_CN = as.numeric(as.character(dados_enem$NOTA_CN))
>   max(dados_enem$NOTA_CN)
>   [1] NA

O arquivo é bem grande (quase 9 milhões de registros e 166 colunas, mas segue uma amostra dos dados desta coluna:

```
[4513]    NA    NA 462.1 483.1 541.7    NA 527.8    NA    NA 456.9 639.5 527.9 535.1    NA    NA    NA  
 [4529] 505.7 389.3 391.7 764.9 527.5 459.3 481.1    NA 438.7 609.3 591.8 438.3 538.2    NA 493.5    NA  
 [4545]    NA 396.8    NA 486.3 566.1    NA    NA    NA 529.8 620.5 477.0 404.4 446.2 547.4    NA 460.5  
 [4561]    NA    NA 541.8    NA    NA 544.2 605.2 584.5    NA    NA 523.2 541.7    NA 523.1 528.7    NA
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Grato a todos!

Comment: Vc tentou excluindo as linhas com NA? Vc pode usar `dados_enem = na.omit(dados_enem)` ou fazer a chamada de cálculo da seguinte forma: `mean(dados_enem$NOTA_CN, na.rm=TRUE)`. 
Mais detalhes aqui: http://www.statmethods.net/input/missingdata.html

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou com a opção na.rm=TRUE. Muito grato!
Uma dúvida, quando eu uso a opção na.omit(), ele apensa ignora os dados nulos ou os remove?

Comment: @Sandro com o `na.omit` os dados são removidos do objeto. Além disso, é importante lembrar que ele exclui todas as linhas que possuem pelo menos um valor `NA`.

Comment: Como o colega @DanielFalbel comentou, o `na.omit` remove todas as linhas onde ao menos uma coluna tenha `NA`. Assim, se em uma certa linha, uma das colunas tem um `NA` que vc poderia ignorar pontualmente (por exemplo, ao calcular a média *daquela* coluna), lembre-se que se usar o `na.omit` toda aquela linha será eliminada (e os dados, válidos, das outras colunas vão ser perdidos). Tem que se analisar caso a caso, pois as vezes aquele `NA` não é problemático, e as vezes sua falta é suficientemente importante para invalidar todo o restante das colunas.

Comment: No seu caso, por exemplo, a nota parece ser bastante importante. Então, uma linha em que tem `NA` justamente nessa coluna *talvez* possa ser totalmente eliminada porque os demais dados daquela linha tornar-se-iam inúteis pra análise que vc quer fazer.

Comment: Entendi @LuizVieira, grato pela explicação!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
max(dados_enem$NOTA_CN, na.rm = TRUE)  
min(dados_enem$NOTA_CN, na.rm = TRUE)  
mean(dados_enem$NOTA_CN, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Por padrão, essas funções retornam resultado NA quando existem dados NA no vetor. Você precisa explicitamente avisar que deseja excluí-los do resultado.

Isso confunde muito quem está começando no R pois, inclusive não existe um padrão entre as suas funções. Por exemplo, a função `summary` e a função `table` por padrão ignoram a presença de `NA`'s

Comment: Funcionou! Seria prudente então sempre esta opção, correto?  
Muito grato!

Comment: @Sandro, depende muito do que você quer. Muitas vezes `NA`'s representam alguma informação que poderia ser usada no cálculo da média e não devem necessariamente ser excluidos.

Comment: Entendo, mas, com o perdão da ignorância, se os campos contendo NA impedem o cálculo da média, já que a função retorna NA quando os encontra, como eles poderiam ser incluídos neste cálculo? Não sei se entendi bem...

Comment: @Sandro O `default` `FALSE` é mais prudente. Ele evita que uma função sobre 1000 valores em que 900 são `NA` retorne um resultado numérico como se não houvessem valores faltantes, gerando uma informação possivelmente incorreta ou tendenciosa. A exigência da definição de `na.rm = TRUE` explicitamente faz com que o programador assuma o risco de ignorar os valores `NA`.

Comment: Daniel, acho uma boa ideia sempre usar `FALSE` e `TRUE` nas respostas, como recomendado em diversos lugares. `T` e `F` são apenas variáveis que podem ser modificadas e gerar problemas. Isso é especialmente importante para novatos, que podem não entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Em tempo: `table` só conta as ocorrências, e pode contar NAs também, então não corre os riscos que citei acima. `summary` informa o número de NAs, quando existem, o que não é tão silencioso como um `na.rm = TRUE` default seria.

Comment: @Molx Acho que a dúvida do AP é mais no sentido de que mesmo com o default `FALSE` sendo mais prudente, qual é o propósito disso uma vez que basta ter um `NA` pra função *sempre* retornar `NA`?

Comment: Exatamente @LuizVieira, se deixar o default como FALSE a função (max, min ou mean) retorna NA. A dúvida seria: para estes casos citados, a função "mean", por exemplo, calcula a média com base em todos os registros (incluindo os com valor NA) ou apenas para os que possuem algum valor (ainda que zero) na coluna? Por exemplo, para um conjunto de 100 linhas, onde 30 possuem NA na coluna usada, a média é calculada com base em 100 ou em 70?